# не могу сохранить фото в базу данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я новичок В Django хотел сохранить фото в базу с файлами. создал форму,  импортировал в модель,  модель импортировал в  views. если же сохранять данные без фото то данные все сохраняются в базе.
forms.py:

```
class  ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=250, label=('Title:'))
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=300, widget=forms.Textarea, 
                  label=('Description:'))
    phone_num = forms.IntegerField(label=('Phone_num:'))
    price = forms.IntegerField(label= ('Price:'))
    first_image_original = forms.ImageField()
```

models.py:

```
class Announcement(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table='announcements'

    title=models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    phone_num=models.IntegerField()
    price=models.IntegerField()
    first_image_original=models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

views.py:

```
def dobavit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/announcement/example')
    else:
        form=ImageUploadForm()
    return render(request, 'announcement/dobavit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Что значит "не могу"? Возникает ошибка? Если да, то какая? Или происходит перенаправление на /announcement/example, а данные в базу не добавляются?

Comment: происходит перенаправление на announcement/example.html.  думал что сохранилось-проверяю базу данных- но данных нет

Answer (score 1):

Ваша форма понятия не имеет о том, что должна сохранять какую-то модель. Замените её на

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Announcement
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: заменил форму но в cmd выдает ошибку:      from .forms import ImageUploadForm
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\env\obyavlenie\Scripts\mysite\announcement\forms.py"
, line 2, in <module>
    from .models import Announcement
ImportError: cannot import name 'Announcement'

Comment: Не может импортировать модель. Проверьте отсутствие циклических импортов.

Comment: изменил форму-запустил локально-но в базу не сохраняет.  заполняю все поля нажимаю на Добавить-перенаправлениий уже нет но страничка обновляется и все

Answer (score 0):

Так же мучился, просто нужно добавить в форму **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data novalidate>
```

З.Ы. причём в других местах, всё тоже самое позволяет загрузить фото, а в некоторых приходиться вставлять это в форму.